# How do Facebook, Google, and many others keep me (securely) logged in for so long?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization, single-page-application

So I've been looking at creating a a website. How exactly has not been decided, but lets say I'm going to use a React.js single page application (SPA) that interacts with a REST API.

This is fine and all, but at some point I am going to have to log users into this site. In looking into this problem, I have learnt about OAuth's implicit (or authorization code without a secret) grant, which is what they claim **should** be used when dealing with authorization in SPAs. The reasoning behind this is that there is no way for them to securely store a client secret, and thus they should only be given access to relatively short lived access codes. This being true for client-side authentication and authorization in general.

The problem, of course, is that every time your access token expires you need your user to re-authorize, as you now have no way of refreshing this access token.

Despite this, websites like Google, Facebook and Github (among many others) seem to keep me permanently logged into their systems. Surely this means they are storing some sort of session ID permanently within the browser and thus this suffers the **exact** same problems as to why you shouldn't use client secrets in OAuth?

So how do they deal with this? Are they just, effectively, using very long lived access codes or session IDs and say "screw security"? I mean, Google **force** me to use short-lived access codes if I want to make an application that requests their data, so why do their own apps and website not suffer from this?

Comment: Cookies? Just delete your cookies and you will be logged out.

Comment: read up on access tokens AND refresh tokens

Comment: Sessions can be refreshed during continual use. Refreshing tokens doesn't have to perform visible redirects. Silent hidden iframe authentication is possible

Comment: All these comments do not answer my question. OAuth implicit grant (or auorization without secret) do NOT give you a refresh token.

OAuth specifically does this because a browser cannot be secured to keep a secret (this is the browser requesting access, not the server), and thus must be re-authenticated over and over.

So my question is whether these sites ignore that for the sake of convenience. Or whether this security is about something else.